# Wrapping HTML between PHP tags in IF statement

Tags: php, html

This may be a simple question but I'd like to know if it is viable to do this.

```
<?php
if($something == "true")
{
?>

<p>MANY lines of html code.</p>

<?php
}
?>
```

Is this viable? It would make my life easier.

Comment: That is what basic PHP is designed for

Comment: I've always been using echo to print out HTML in IF statements.

Comment: tested it? if it it works its *viable*

Comment: Using templates is by far the best way to handle this as you can manipulate anything without having to mix both together see Smarty or a framework like codeigniter.

Comment: $something == "true" or $something === true?

Answer (score 3):

What you've done is the correct way to mixed between PHP and HTML. You can also use `echo`:

```
<?php
    if($something == "true") { 
        echo "<p>MANY lines of html code.</p>"
    }
?>
```

You can use `$something` instead of `$something == "true"` as well.

You can also consider to use a PHP template engine such as **[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)**

Comment: Thanks,  yeah I've always used Echo.

Comment: For fast convert parts of html to **PHP echo or print statements** you can use some of online tool like [HTML to PHP Converter](https://wtools.io/html-to-php-converter) just past your html code and click convert. No more "escape" issues.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, it might be more readable to use an include statement with a template instead.

```
if($something == "true") {
    include("yourtemplate.html");
}
```

Comment: why is this down voted?  I'm not saying it shouldn't be down voted, but I'd like to know why this wouldn't be ok

Comment: seems like putting the include inside the if statement would make the code much more readable.  I suppose you can be in for some trouble if the file can't be found

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I can clearly see why. It's obvious the OP is still learning PHP, so how can a single line of code, which does nothing more than 'kind of' pointing into a direction will help him? With no further explanation it's completely meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The way PHP works is that for the entire file, you can go between PHP elements and HTML elements as much as you'd like. Instead of thinking of the file as PHP-only, think of it as HTML with PHP elements. You can mix and match these elements throughout the PHP file.

For instance, you could do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo title(); ?></title>
    </head>
</html>
```

or you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    //do some work 
    $title = $_POST['title'];
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
</html>

<?php
    //do some more work 
    $body = $_POST['body'];
?>
```

Mixing HTML and PHP is perfectly fine and you can go between them with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is viable.

Note then that if you need to use php variables in your html code you can use this :

```
<?=$someVariable?>
```